# Rest-assured: Modify body before checking response body

Tags: java, json, rest

Situation:
I use rest-assured to do rest calls and I want to use it to check the response.

But for specific reasons there is something added in front of every json that gets returned. Is there a way to automatically remove this with rest assured so that I can actually process the context of the file using rest assured or do I have to clean it up myself and use a different library to validate the response body?

Edit:
For now i use the following workaround:

```
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseBody);
String title = jsonPath.getString("x.y.title");
```

So I still use the internal json parser but I process the response manually (after cleaning the json up).

Answer (score 0):

You will be knowing the key added in front of every json. So you can use the key like
`JsonObject keyJson = null;
 if(jsonPath.has("key")) {
    keyJson = JsonObject keyJson = jsonPath.get("key");
 }`
 now from the keyJson if you are sure it has the expected value, you can take  **"x.y.title"**

Comment: The thing in front is not vallid json so that wont work